# How to get a value from an xml directly (preferably using XPath)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am trying to get comp1's value in the most simple way in C#. I want to be able to do it with a way that requires least checkes whether an element like Primary is there, etc.

i.e.

```
//  pseudo code
xmlItem = root.SelectSingleNode "/Primary/Complex?Name='comp1'"
```

So I can just check if `xmlItem` is `null`, or has no elements, instead of doing many checks everytime I access a child node. Here is the xml, but the actual one is more nested, but only the leaf xml node has a specific name that we are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Primary Type="">
   <Simple Name="smp"></Simple>
   <Complex Name="comp0" Value="123"></Complex>
   <Complex Name="comp1" Value="456"></Complex>
   <Complex Name="comp2" Value="789"></Complex>
</Primary>
```

Comment: IMHO C# + XML + Best-practices = LINQ to XML (at least in 3.5), not XPath. Check out XElement and XDocument in System.Xml.Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xmlItem = root.SelectSingleNode("/Primary/Complex[@Name='comp1']/@Value");
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the XPath is `/Primary/Complex[@Name='comp0']/@Value`

By the way, your XML is wrong. No closing tag for Simple, no opening tag for Material. I've assumed `</Material>` should be `</Simple>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
root.SelectSingleNode("/Primary/Complex[@Name='comp1']/@Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the XPathDocument and XPathNavigator from the System.Xml.XPath namespace.

```
XPathDocument fileToParse = new XPathDocument(FullPathToFile);
XPathNavigator fileNavigator = fileToParse.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator selected = fileNavigator.SelectSingleNode("./Primary/Complex[@Name='comp1']/@Value");
//selected will be null if your XPath doesn't select anything...
if(selected != null){ Console.WriteLine(selected.Value); }
```